# vue.js passing data back to a component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good evening.
I am creating a chat application with laravel and `vue.js`. I have all the messages listed for my user but now I made conversations selectable so whenever a user selects any of them a particular conversation messages would appear. I console.log'ed the data and whenever I click on the conversation, I can see that I have an array of messages that are needed, but I can't figure out the way how to pass them back to app.js, where `messages[]` array is so I could re-render the component to list all the messages for that particular conversation. Some of the code here is not properly validated so just ignore that because for now I am focusing on how to pass back the data.
Thanks!

ChatConversation.vue

```
export default {
    props: ['conversation'],
    methods: {
        getMessages(conversation_id) {
            this.messages = [];
            axios.get('/messages/' + conversation_id, conversation_id).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                // HOW TO SEND THEM BACK???
            });
        }
    }
}
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    messages: [],
    conversations: [],
},
methods: {
    addMessage(message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
        axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {

        });
    },
    loadMessages(messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
},
created() {
    axios.get('/conversations').then(response => {
        this.conversations = response.data;
    });

    axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
        this.messages = response.data;
    });

    Echo.join('chatroom')
        .listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
            this.messages.push({
                message: e.message.message,
                user: e.user
            });

            console.log(e);
        });

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I'd recommend using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) or another way of maintaining state. The idea is, you receive data from the api, place it in a vuex store that is available between components, and leverage reactivity to notify the intended recipient that data is available.

When used with a plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate), your data can persist between browser sessions.

A general work flow would look like this:

```
axios.get('/messages/' + conversation_id, conversation_id).then(response => {
     // HOW TO SEND THEM BACK???
     this.$store.commit('setMessages', response.data)
});
```

Then in `app.js` you would use vuex's helper functions:

```
computed: {
     ...mapGetters({
          messages: 'getMessages'
     })
}
```

The messages computed will now be reactive, meaning that you can use it in your template or other computeds and they will update accordingly:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
             {{ message.content }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```