# How to communicate between components within a certain component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have a tree of component like this:

```
<widget>
  <widget-header>
    <panel-toggle></panel-toggle>
  </widget-header>
  <widget-body>
    <panel></panel>
  </widget-body>
</widget>
```

Now supposed I want the `panel-toggle` component to be able to toggle the visibility of the `panel` component. I could have it affect a prop passed down from `widget` through to each component, but that didn't seem like the best solution. I tried sending an event with `this.$emit(eventName)` but the event is only picked up by the immediate parent of the element emitting the event. In this case, that would be `panel-toggle` emitting the event and only `widget-header` being able to pick it up. I tried sending the event across the root element with `this.$root.$emit(eventName)` and picking it up with `this.$root.$on(eventName)`, but then it is picked up by all `widget` components and that is no good. What I ended up doing is sending the event with `this.$parent.$parent.$emit(eventName)` and then picking it up from `panel` with `this.$parent.$parent.$on(eventName)`. While that worked, it doesn't seem like the right way to go about this.

What would be the correct way to achieve this communication between components within the component `widget` only with Vue? Is the answer somehow related to the `ref` feature?

Comment: Inter component communication is typically handled via events (as you demonstrated) or with state management, i.e. Vuex. I've answered the Vuex side [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631718/320487)

Comment: adding to what btl mentioned you could use an [EventBus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/),

Comment: Now, I did look at that. Perhaps I don't understand, but isn't it for passing events around an application globally? In my example wouldn't the `panel-toggle` affect every `panel` in the application, which would not be the desired behavior? Could I use a Vue Event Bus to send events within a particular component, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're concerned (and with good reason) about the globalness of a global event bus, the solution is a localized event bus. Create a data item in the parent:

```
panelBus: new Vue()
```

and pass it to each of the children as a prop. Now they have a private communcation channel for just the two of them.

Comment: example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754830/vuejs-listening-for-event-on-component/47759612#47759612

Comment: @VolodymyrSymonenko That is an example of a global event bus.

Comment: sorry, I hurried with the answer)